# How to Create New Classes on RunTime C#

Tags: c#, class, runtime

i have xml file  Like this

```
<Student>
    <column Type="String">Name</column>
    <column Type="Int32">Age</column>
 </Student>
```

i am using VS2008.i don't know columns at runtime.i.e extra columns can add to xml file.

Now my question is How to create class of this and store this type(created class) in (C#)Generics.i.e List,etc.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Generics are mostly about knowing more type information at *compile-time*. If you only know the type information at execution time, it's not clear what benefit there'll be. Please give more details about what you're trying to *do* with this information.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you have classes generated at runtime the rest of your application still do not know them, and therefore cannot use them.

Comment: Do you really mean you don't know the columns at runtime? Or at compile-time?

Answer (score 1):

That is really hard; if you absolutely wanted to do that *as runtime classes*, you'd have to look at `TypeBuilder` etc. Frankly, unless you are already familiar with that, or this is *really* important, it probably isn't worth it. Not least: you can't really code against such objects, except as `object`.

Your best bet might be to use some kind of DOM (`XmlDocument`, `XElement` etc) to read the data, but populate perhaps into a `DataTable`. I'm not really a big fan of `DataTable` in regular code, but it exists, and would fit this scenario nicely.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach(XmlElement child in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("column"))
{
    table.Columns.Add(child.InnerText, ParseType(child.GetAttribute("Type")));
}
....
static Type ParseType(string type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case "String": return typeof(string);
        case "Int32": return typeof(int);
        default: throw new NotSupportedException(type ?? "(null)");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also the `ExpandoObject`, though it's not a new type but rather an object that can have dynamic properties which is probably all that matters in his probable use-case.

Comment: @Jeff since the columns aren't known ahead of time, there won't be code talking to `obj.Foo`, even via `dynamic`. However, the *dictionary* aspect of `ExpandoObject` may have utility. The reason I didn't suggest that option is that then you're storing all the keys etc per object, rather than once for all objects, which `DataTable` (while it pains me deep down) does.

Answer (score -1):

First make a class called Student and make it serializeable, then add 2 properties Name and Age.

then feed the xml to this function

```
public static Object XMLStringToObject(string xml, Type objectType)
{
    object obj = null;
    XmlSerializer ser = null;
    StringReader stringReader = null;
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
    try
    {
        ser = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
        stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
        obj = ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Do nothing for now
    }
    finally
    {
        xmlReader.Close();
        stringReader.Close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

There are more smaller serialize functions, but this is just to show u quickly how to serialize yr object, cause normally you would use `XMLStringToObject<T>`